# gcc 2.03 gives cc1.exe :"out of memory alloction" error while compilation with 32-bit windows 7 OS

Tags: gcc, windows-7, djgpp

I am using djgpp 2.03 version and 32-bit windows 7 OS with 3 GB RAM, but while compiling the c source code, I am getting the error "cc1.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes after a total of 52828808 bytes" same source code is getting correctly compiled with the windows xp system with same utility(djgpp 2.03).I tried by increasing virtual memory space to few GB but didn't work,please help me to out of this issue......

Thanks and Best Regars
Rupesh thakur

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using a dos version of GCC in Windows?

Comment: we are using it as per the customer demand since long duration,and we didnot face any issue with windoe xp,and this software migration needs some aprrovals also,but is it only problem with DOS version?

Comment: I'm not expert on Windows, but this is normal.

Comment: Hello Rupesh, I am also facing the same problem have you found out a solution for this? if so please share it here as this page comes as a top result in google when the problem is serched.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to run dos programs in Windows, you should consider virtualization.

Yes, some dos programs will work even without virtualization, but some won't. This seems to be an example of the later.

Comment: @rupesh Well, use virtualization to run the djgpp in actual DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try with (unfortunately unreleased) version 2.04 of DJGPP. Follow these [instructions](http://www.trnicely.net/misc/djgpp204.html).  This version has much better compatibility with recent versions of Windows, where "recent" means Windows 2000 and above.  (I cannot believe I am saying this in 2010).